# Run python code within python as if from bash when compiled

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have the next code:

main1.py:

```py
from local_module import func

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
    # change dir to path_to_main2
    # dynamically import main2.py
    # here I want to run main2.main() in the new environment
    # e.g.: call subprocess.call(['python' 'main2'])
    # but the problem is described in the question!
```

main2.py (it is in an another directory):

```py
# this is not that local_module above, but it has the same name
from local_module import func

def main():
    func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So the question is the next:

I want to compile (with PyInstaller) this code for Windows without python installed. Thus, as I understand, `subprocess.call(['python' 'main2'])` won't work after the compilation. But if I run `main2.main()` within the `main1.py`, I will be having `local_module` and `func()` already imported and another `func()` (local one, but not from `main2`) will be executed. How can I deal with it?

P.S. I can't modify/edit `main2.py` anyhow to avoid name intersections, and I am not able to predict whether there will be name intersections or not

Comment: Can you rename `local_module` you're pulling from within the `main1.py` path?

Comment: As Python is not installed on the target system you won't be able to call the `python`command. So you could just import the needed function from  main2.py and run it from there.

Comment: @zwer, I can rename `main1.py` modules, but as I wrote in P.S., I am not able to predict if there is any collisions. For example, I can rename it to `new_local_module`, but `main3.py` (which is new cause I import them dynamically) may have that `new_local_module` too.

Comment: @MrLeeh, But if I run `main2` within `main1`, needed module (`local_module`), which has the same name as in `main1` but is different, is already imported and python will not import it in `main2.py`

Comment: You can import the local_module with `from main2 import local_module as local_module_main2` to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: @MrLeeh - after the initial module load, the loaded modules are cached by name so `import local_module` will always point to the same module no matter how you decide to name it in your current namespace.

Comment: @MrLeeh, no, I don't even import `main2` modules (btw, local_module not in main2, but in the same dir) in `main1`. `main2` uses its own modules, `main1` uses its own. But if the module names are the same, python will not import one of them and use imported one.

Comment: @ospanoff - then why don't you unload `local_module` completely (as in - remove it from the modules list) in `main1.py` before you call the function to switch the context to `main2`? Since you're switching context you shouldn't care about your `main1.py` anyway. Btw, you have a very weird and not-at-all recommended setup - I'm quite certain you're approaching the whole thing wrong for the goal you want to achieve, maybe you should rethink your project instead of forcing Python/PyInstaller to act as they are not supposed to.

Comment: @zwer, 1st, Python does not support unloading modules. 2nd, I don't know what modules are being loaded in `main2.py` =). 3rd, I swtich back to main1 when main2 has been completed.

Comment: @ospanoff - Yes it does. Not directly but it's relatively easy to achieve - just remove your module from `sys.modules` after importing it and keep only a local reference in `main1.py`, that should solve both of your problems. However, I'd urge you again to rethink your strategy as what you're doing is everything but a good app design.

Comment: @ospanoff Maybe you could clarify the structure a bit more in your question. I think If you are using Python3 you could use relative imports to make sure you get the right module.

Comment: @zwer, I am already rethinking of the design =) But can't find a good solution. I am writing a program that runs another programs and when those programs are finished the control is given back to the main program.

Comment: @ospanoff - So you're recreating REPL/IDLE with a custom menu? Then do what they do - bundle a Python interpreter with your app and use it to run external programs as intended without hacking the environment as you can never simulate it perfectly - many have tried to create sandboxed Python and none of them succeeded (apart from running it in a thin hypervisor). If you insist to build everything in Python, you can at least use [`pynsist`](https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist), as it bundles CPython with your app, and then you can use the bundled Python to run arbitrary scripts.

Comment: @zwer, Thank you for your suggestion. If it gives a good performance as if I compile with PyInstaller, then I will use it!